# How to display the results of a function in a seperate GUI?

Tags: java, user-interface, windowbuilder

So, using WindowBuilder and eclipse, I have made certain functionality which reads a text file and displays certain data - I want to link this result to a JFrame that I have made in a separate class

These are the codes for each:

This is my public class adminAccounts:

```
File inputFile = new File("UserAccounts.txt");
Scanner fileScanner = new Scanner(inputFile);
String s="admin";
int i;

while (fileScanner.hasNextLine()) 
{
String line = fileScanner.nextLine();
String[] arr = line.split(",");

if(arr[6].contains(s)) 
{
    //System.out.println(arr[1]);
}
```

And this is my class AdminUsers which currently is a JFrame with a header and I would like to display the results of adminAccounts into the JFrame

```
private JPanel contentPane;

public static void AdminFrame() {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                AdminUsers frame = new AdminUsers();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the frame.
 */
public AdminUsers() {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBackground(new Color(255, 255, 204));
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    contentPane.setLayout(null);

    JLabel Header = new JLabel("Choose from the following Admin usernames:");
    Header.setBounds(10, 11, 321, 14);
    contentPane.add(Header);

    JLabel result = new JLabel();
    result.setBounds(184, 47, 46, 14);
    contentPane.add(result);
}
```

Please help as I am new to this and very confused!

Comment: Do you want to read a list of names from a text file and display that list in a `JList` ?

Comment: yeah, I dont know whether to do it as a JList or something else? I'm not really sure, just need to be able to display the names in the Frame

Comment: For learning _Swing_, I recommend the [Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html) "trail" which is one of Oracle's java tutorials.